# What is the Intellij keyboard shortcut to go to start/end of argument list (enclosed in rounded brackets)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

A Java code block is delimited by  `{` braces `}` and moving the cursor to the start and end of these is a common use case for a developer. As such, the **JetBrains** IDE **Intellij** has shortcuts for these. They are:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> Go to block start

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> Go to block end

A function's argument list in Java is delimited by `(` round brackets `)` and quite often we want to be at the beginning or end of this bit of code. What are the respective shortcuts for this functionality?

Comment: I only know Ctrl+Shift+M to move to the other part of a brace, but nothing that explicitly goes to the next or previous `(` or `)`

Comment: @Link64 Works the same for a method's argument list.

Comment: @Ascalonian the only users will be programmers though. I don't think many SU would know the answer to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> will toggle you between the starting and closing parentheses.

The name of this function in the key map is "Move Caret to Matching Brace" if you wanted to change it to something else.